# rStudio/Shiny: calculate medians from a rendered table

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm able to subset a data table based on user selections in the following code but I'd also like to calculate and display the median value for the ohsi column based on the user input.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("HSI Explorer"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("type",label="choose CAH/NON-CAHs",choices=list("CAH","NON-CAH")),
    radioButtons("system",label="choose SYSTEM/NON-SYSTEM",choices=list("SYSTEM","NON-SYSTEM")),
    radioButtons("teaching",label="choose TEACHING/NON-TEACHING",choices=list("TEACHING","NON-TEACHING"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("mOut"),
      tableOutput("table1")
  )
)))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
datan <- read.csv("data/hsi.csv")
tcols <- c("provid","st","ohsi")
ocols <- c("ohsi")
datax <- datan[tcols]
datao <- datan[ocols]
shinyServer(function(input, output){
rTable <- renderTable({
datax[which(datan$tnt==input$teaching & datan$sysnsys==input$system & datan$cahncah==input$type),]
})
median <- median(rTable$ohsi)
output$table1 <- rTable
output$mOut <- renderText({
paste("the median for your selection is: "m,
}) 
}  
)
```

Comment: To get an answer, it would be helpful if you could provide hsi.csv, or better generate a sample data set on the fly. It needs 5 minutes go generate an answer when the data are available, and 15 minute without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without data it is hard to give an exact answer but you could define your data as a reactive function and use it to feed `renderTable` and `renderText`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  myData <- reactive({
    datax[which(datan$tnt==input$teaching & datan$sysnsys==input$system & datan$cahncah==input$type),]
  })
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    myData()
  })
  output$mOut <- renderText({
    m <- median(myData()$ohsi)
    paste("the median for your selection is: ", m)
  }) 
}  
)
```

Comment: Thank you, jdharrison! Your suggestion to define my data as a reactive function is just what I needed. Many thanks!